# Total number of WW, WR, RW conflicts in the given example?

Tags: database-theory

```
+---+------+------+
|   | T1   | T2   |
+---+------+------+
| 1 | W(A) |      |
| 2 |      | R(A) |
| 3 | W(A) |      |
| 4 |      | R(A) |
| 5 | W(A) |      |
| 6 |      | W(A) |
| 7 | W(A) |      |
| 8 |      | W(A) |
+---+------+------+
```

In the above scenario can someone tell me how many WW, WR, RW conflicts are there? Can we say that there is a WR(write read) conflict between transactions 1 and 2 from statement 1 to statement 4? As the A value is updated at statement 3, 4th statement read conflicts only with 3rd statement write but not 1st statement write. Can someone tell me in total how many WW, WR, RW conflicts are there between the two transactions?

Answer (score 0):

WW conflicts are --> 1-6, 1-8 , 3-6, 3-8, 5-6, 5-8, 7-8, 6-7

RW conflicts are --> 2-3, 2-5, 2-7, 4-5, 4-7

WR conflicts are --> 1-2, 1-4, 3-4